# Fundamental solution of second order differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Consider the differential operator $\left(\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}+a \frac{d}{d x}+b\right)=L, a, b$ constants.

Fundamental solution $F$ of second order operator $L$ is given by $LF=\delta$.

Let $f$ and $g$ satisfy $L f=0, L g=0, f(0)=g(0), f^{\prime}(0)-g^{\prime}(0)=1$. Consider the function
$$
F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
f(x), x \geqslant 0 \\
g(x), x<0
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then I wanted to show that $F$ is a fundamental solution for $L .$

We can write $F(x)=H(x)\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)+g(x)$ where $H(x)$ is Heaviside step function.

From linearity, one can deduce that $LF=0$ everywhere except at $x=0$.

I know that derivative of distribution generated by Heaviside function is Dirac delta function. But unable to use that here.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct mathematical way to show this is to take a test function $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ and show that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x) \, L^*\varphi(x) \, dx = \varphi(0),
$$
where $L^* = \frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}-a \frac{d}{d x}+b.$

Inserting the definition of $F$ into the left hand side gives
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x) \, L^*\varphi(x) \, dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} g(x) \, \left(\varphi''(x)-a\varphi'(x)+b\varphi(x)\right) \, dx\\
&+ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, \left(\varphi''(x)-a\varphi'(x)+b\varphi(x)\right) \, dx
.
\end{align}$$

Integrating by parts, moving derivatives from $\varphi$ to $g$ and $f$ we get
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x) \, L^*\varphi(x) \, dx
&= \left[ g(x)\,\varphi'(x) - g'(x)\,\varphi(x) - g(x)\,\varphi(x) \right]_{-\infty}^{0} \\
&+ \int_{-\infty}^{0} \left( g''(x)+ag'(x)+bg(x)\right) \, \varphi(x) \, dx \\
&+ \left[ f(x)\,\varphi'(x) - f'(x)\,\varphi(x) - f(x)\,\varphi(x) \right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
&+ \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( f''(x) + af'(x) + bf(x) \right) \, \varphi(x) \, dx
.
\end{align}$$

Here the integrals vanish and the $[\ldots]$ parts vanish at $\pm\infty$ so we are left with
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x) \, L^*\varphi(x) \, dx
&= \left( g(0) \, \varphi'(0) - g'(0) \, \varphi(0) - g(0) \, \varphi(0) \right) \\
&- \left( f(0) \, \varphi'(0) - f'(0) \, \varphi(0) - f(0) \, \varphi(0) \right) \\
&= \left( g(0)-f(0) \right) \varphi'(0) - \left( g'(0)-f'(0) \right) \varphi(0) - \left( g(0) - f(0) \right) \varphi(0) \\
&= 0 \varphi'(0) - (-1)\varphi(0) - 0\varphi(0) \\
&= \varphi(0).
\end{align}$$